# Try catch in java

Tags: java, exception

If I have the following code:

```
try {
    Entity questionEntity = datastore.get(currentKey); 
    questionEntity.doSomething();
} catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
    Entity questionEntity = new Entity(currentKey);
}
```

Where the `datastore.get()` function throws an exception, will the following lines of code (`questionEntity.doSomething();`) in the try block be executed?

Comment: That (questionEntity.doSomething()) line is executed if and only if the previous line hasn't caused exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, `questionEntity.doSomething();` will won't be executed if `datastore.get(currentKey);` throws an exception and this is trivially easy to verify and would have probably taken you less time to try it out yourself rather than posting a question on SO.

Comment: I know just I didn't have access to my computer which I normally use. I was pretty sure it would skip, but had to be sure. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jonathan., well now you can be sure :-)

Comment: thanks :) I find this try-catch block "thing" a bit messy, is it ok to put try-catch blocks inside each other?

Comment: @Jonathan., nesting too many try/catch blocks inside one another makes the code less readable IMHO. I would avoid it.

Answer (score 7):

No, if `get` throws an exception, control will transfer *either* to the catch block shown (if the exception is an `EntityNotFoundException`) or higher up the stack otherwise. It won't just continue onto the next line.

Part of the point of exceptions is to avoid the code continuing to try to work as if nothing has happened when something has gone wrong. This avoids you (say) overwriting good data with corrupt or incomplete data if the data fetching failed.

Answer (score 2):

No:

1. If EntityNotFoundException, the catch will be executed
2. If any other Exception, the exception will be thrown up to calling code.
3. Consider a finally clause if code MUST be executed.  (In this case, that wouldn't work, because this is the only place the entity is initialized

Answer (score 2):

No it will not. The code will continue to the catch block immediately after the exception. Skipping all code after the exception.

Answer (score 1):

No - it will jump immediately to:

```
Entity questionEntity = new Entity(currentKey);
```

...in your catch{} block.